# Parse.com push notifications not shown in background on android

Tags: cordova, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging, ionic-framework, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm using Parse.com with an Ionic app and the PushPlugin and trying to implement Parse's Push Notifications through GCM with a custom Sender ID.

When I'm sending a message to all devices, or using the REST API with cURL,
iOS notifications trigger fine when the app is in the background but android notifications are not.

Here's what I tried with the rest API First for iOS, which is working well:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APP-ID" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: API-KEY" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "where": {
          "deviceType": "ios"
        },
        "data": {
          "alert": "Hello World!"
        }
      }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

The iOS notification is received and displayed even when the app is closed or open in the background.

Now, when I try the same targeting for android devices:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APP-ID" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: API-KEY" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "where": {
          "deviceType": "android"
        },
        "data": {
          "alert": "Hello World!"
        }
      }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

The notification is received by the device and partially logged in `adb logcat` but is not displayed in the notification bar or otherwise acknowledged. I tried changing `'alert'` to `'message'` but that had no effect.

However, if I try to use the GCM HTTP API with Postman or cURL, everything works well:

```
curl 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' \
  -H 'authorization: key=API-KEY' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
        "registration_ids" : [
          "DEVICE-REGISTRATION-ID"
        ],
        "data" : {
          "message": "You Go I Go, Buddy!"
        }
      }'
```

When logging `adb logcat` the logs are different when using the GCM API and Parse's Push Notifications API:

With Parse:

```
I/GCM     (10319): GCM message co.yougoigo.mobile 0:1423318254669687%bd9ff524f9fd7ecd
V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(11506): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(11506): GCM IntentService class: com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService
V/GCMBaseIntentService(11506): Acquiring wakelock
V/GCMBaseIntentService(11506): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-GCMIntentService-3
D/GCMIntentService(11506): onMessage - context: android.app.Application@251ee33b
```

And with GCM cURL call:

```
I/GCM     (10319): GCM message co.yougoigo.mobile 0:1423318321652064%bd9ff524f9fd7ecd
I/ActivityManager(  745): Start proc co.yougoigo.mobile for broadcast co.yougoigo.mobile/com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver: pid=11788 uid=10187 gids={50187, 9997, 3003} abi=armeabi-v7a
V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(11788): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
V/GCMRegistrar(11788): Setting the name of retry receiver class to com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver
V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(11788): GCM IntentService class: com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService
V/GCMBaseIntentService(11788): Acquiring wakelock
V/GCMBaseIntentService(11788): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-GCMIntentService-1
D/GCMIntentService(11788): onMessage - context: android.app.Application@251ee33b
E/GCMIntentService(11788): Number format exception - Error parsing Notification ID: Invalid int: "null"
V/GCMBaseIntentService(11788): Releasing wakelock
```

The current manifest is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="4" android:versionName="0.0.4" package="co.yougoigo.mobile" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="CordovaApp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity" />
        <receiver android:name="com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="co.yougoigo.mobile" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fb_app_id" />
        <activity android:label="@string/fb_app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="co.yougoigo.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="co.yougoigo.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Does anyone have any experience in getting GCM notifications to work on phonegap apps?

Comment: I am having the same exact experience. Any luck on this? How did you setup your installation in parse?

Comment: The reason the notifications are not shown is because Parse sends android notifications to a different, custom receiver. You have to include the Parse SDK using something like https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin but for me the plugin breaks. What I ended up doing is sending android push notifications directly through GCM and not Parse Push.

Comment: That was my suspicion. I was also trying to use the same parse-plugin but it would crash every time it opens. I'm guessing that means you aren't developing for iOS then. I'm looking for a good hybrid solution.

Comment: I opened an issue on the parse-plugin repo but so far it hasn't moved. I am developing for iOS actually and my terrible workaround is to use a Cloud Code helper that sorts installations by device type and only uses Parse Push for iOS, the rest go to GCM with a REST request. To be honest, I'm thinking of just implementing my own push server on Heroku with node-apns and use a custom solution altogether.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have a solution... I'll update when I verify. It's definitely not a push plugin issue. Its how parse wraps their data and it's parsed in GCMIntentService.java basically parse wraps their data one layer deeper than the push plugin is expecting.

Comment: I would LOVE to know if you manage, please update :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use the phonegap/cordova PushPlugin with Parse Push you have to make the realization that Parse actually wraps it's content in a non standard way. This results in PushPlugin receiving the push notification when the app is in the foreground, but not when it is in the background.

Source code snippet from GCMIntentService.java

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessage - context: " + context);

    // Extract the payload from the message
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {
        // if we are in the foreground, just surface the payload, else post it to the statusbar
        if (PushPlugin.isInForeground()) {
            extras.putBoolean("foreground", true);
            PushPlugin.sendExtras(extras);
        }
        else {
            extras.putBoolean("foreground", false);

            // Send a notification if there is a message
            if (extras.getString("message") != null && extras.getString("message").length() != 0) {
                createNotification(context, extras);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see when the check for `PushPlugin.isInForeground()` fails it checks for a 'message' property on the extras bundle.

2 Observations:

1. Parse does not include a 'message' on the notification so the PushPlugin doesn't call `createNotification(content, extras)`
2. If you look at the 'payload' property of the bundle it also wraps it one layer deeper than "traditional" GCM notifications by putting the notification an object with the key 'data'.

Here's what the bundle looks like in JSON

```
{ ...
  "payload" : {
    "data" : { 
      "message" : "your message here",
      "title": "your title here",
      ...,
      "customData": { ... }
    }
}
```

You, therefore, have to do some custom logic to extract the payload from the bundle `extras.getString("payload")` and then create a new JSONObject (documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Instead of check `bundle.getString("message")` you need to check for check for the existence of payload.data and then parse out message and title and make sure they are in the correct locations for the createNotification function to work by repackaging the bundle (or creating your own).

My recommendation is to leave the existing code as is, but make a separate check for the parse formatted notification and call a custom createNotification function.

As in:

```
if (PushPlugin.isInForeground()) {
  extras.putBoolean("foreground", true);
  PushPlugin.sendExtras(extras);
} else if (extras.getString("message") && extras.getString("message").length() != 0) {
  extras.putBoolean("foreground", false);
  createNotification(context, extras);
} else {
  JSONObject payload = extras.getString("payload");
  JSONObject data = payload.getJSONObject("data");
  String message = data.getString("alert") //parse puts the message as an alert if you don't use custom json payload
  extras.putString("message", alert)
  createNotification(context, extras)
}
```

Hopefully this helps. Honestly, I wish parse just sent the data like everyone else so that it was compatible with PushPlugin out of the box.

Source code for PushPlugin GCMIntentService.java found here (official github repo): https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/src/android/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java

Comment: That's fantastic @james-gilchrist ! I really have very little experience in Android development and didn't know where to start with this issue.